# 10k-tools are missing the link to the post-feedback

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, 10k-tools

The 10k tools used to have a link to the post feedback

https://android.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback

but this link seems to be missing now.

Comment: [The link was removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209655/post-feedback-link-is-broken), the page is still there though

Comment: So the tool is definitely going to be removed and anonymous users won't be able to give feedback in the future?

Comment: feedback from anon users is still recorded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would appear to be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). This tool was removed a couple weeks ago.

[Post Feedback link is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209655/post-feedback-link-is-broken)

> The way this is architected absolutely does not scale. It's also not something we want to put resources into fixing given opportunity cost and what it would take to refactor.
>
> We will be removing the link in the next build and removing the page and code later in the week. I'm sorry that answer sucks, but it's just not an important feature to us, and it would take a significant time investment to fix.

Comment: Hmm, the issue report is about a existing link pointing to a non working site. In our case it's a non-existing link for a working site/tool. I also assume that they maybe leave the tool for smaller sites that aren't affected by the scaling issues it has.

Comment: Well, I don't have 10k on [so] to see if that page is still there.